# How can I fix this error after installing Electron on Mac with command 'sudo npm install electron -g'

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, npm, electron

I preceded the command with `sudo` because I had **'Permission Denied'** errors on my first attempt. It was suggested to run the command as an Admin, or better still delete the entire electron folder at `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` and reinstall. I did that and installed it the second time but I still got the error below:

> ```
> (node:85821) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdtemp '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron/electron-download-KXtUtz'
> (node:85821) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
> (node:85821) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
>
> + electron@8.0.1
>
> added 85 packages from 93 contributors in 8.968s
> ➜  / electron -v
>
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron/index.js:14
>     throw new Error(**'Electron failed to install correctly, please delete node_modules/electron and try installing again'**)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This finally worked for me:

> **sudo npm install electron -g --unsafe-perm=true**

From this link https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/installation

Answer (score 0):

This is how I installed Electron version 8.2.2 with the global flag:

```
npm install -g --unsafe-perm=true electron
```